# jQuery Mobile Navbar: get active tab

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a jQuery Mobile Navbar with two tabs:

```
<div data-role="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="tab ui-btn-active">Inbound</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="tab">Outbound</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

When a tab is clicked, I want to

- do nothing if it's already the active tab,
- do something if the tab clicked becomes the new active one.

According to the [documentation](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/toolbars/docs-navbar.html), the active tab has class `ui-btn-active`, so I listen for clicks and see if that class is present on the clicked button:

```
$('.tab').click(function() {

  if ( $(this).hasClass('ui-btn-active') ) {
    // already active, do nothing
    console.log("already active");
  } else {
    // newly active, do something
    console.log("newly active");
  }
});
```

This has worked perfectly for months, but I see now that it is entirely dependent on the timing of when the active class is removed from one and added to the other, relative to when the `if` is evaluated. Now, after some unrelated code changes, it works as before on desktop browsers, but on mobile browsers, I only get *already active*, regardless of which button is clicked — i.e. the `if` happens too late.

What is the smartest way to do this? Can someone explain the sequence of events, and how the inconsistent ordering of events can happen? Is `click` the right listener to be using for touchscreen devices?

**EDIT:**

I tried listening for the bubbled event on the parent using `.on()` and inspecting the event object, hoping the class list it contains would be more accurate, but the behavior is the same:

```
$('ul').on('click','a',function(event) {
  alert(event.currentTarget.classList.contains('ui-btn-active'));
});
```

clicking on the inactive tab returns `false` on desktop browsers, as hoped, and `true` on mobile browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO `click` is perfectly fine for this purpose and you can simply use a variable to track the active tab. Here is [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pmatseykanets/j9WfD/)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, I solved this way:

```
$("#myselector").on('click','a',function(event) {

   $("#myselector").find('a').each(function(i) { 
     $(this).removeClass('ui-btn-active');
   });
   $(this).addClass('ui-btn-active');

   //  call to my function

});
```

Answer (score 0):

click has a 300ms delay. Try using "tap" instead of "click"